# How can I change `as.POSIXct` into useful format?

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have following data, and would like to format the Date/Time into a Datetime format to do analysis on.

```
Date    Vt1
02/05/15 14:00  23.611
02/05/15 15:00  28.61
02/05/15 16:00  28.61
02/05/15 17:00  19.608
```

I used following code:

```
Test$betterDate<- as.POSIXct(substr(Test$Date,1,14), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

And keep getting the error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "betterDate", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 3836
```

Comment: what do you mean by useful format?

Comment: `%Y` is for the year using four  digits, i.e. 2015. Try `%y` instead.

Comment: And what do you need `substr()` for?

Comment: How about to read the manual?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the issue is that 2 digit years are `%y` not `%Y`. This works

```
as.POSIXct("02/05/15 14:00", format = "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
[1] "2015-05-02 14:00:00 ART"
```

You might want to check if the timezone is correct (argument `tz` of `as.POSIXct`).

Good luck.